# Find Period intersection in days between 2 time intervals

Tags: c#, datetime, intersection

I need to detect how many days have in common 2 date intervals. For this I am using [`Itenso.TimePeriod`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) nuget in C#. But giving the following scenario, I am getting the wrong result:

```
var start1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 11);
var end1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 15);

var start2 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
var end2 = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1);

var periods = new TimePeriodCollection
{
    new TimeRange(start1, end1),
    new TimeRange(start2, end2),
};
var periodIntersector = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
var intersectedPeriods = periodIntersector.IntersectPeriods(periods);
Console.WriteLine($"intersected days: {intersectedPeriods.Duration.Days}");
```

But since both intervals have the days 14 and 15, I expect that the result is 2, but the console prints this:

```
intersected days: 1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Later edit: Even with this code I am getting the wrong result:

```
var start1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 11);
var end1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 15)+ TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

var start2 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
var end2 = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1);

var t1 = new TimeRange(start1, end1, true);
var t2 = new TimeRange(start2, end2, true);

var timeInterval1 = new TimeInterval(start1, end1);
timeInterval1.EndEdge = IntervalEdge.Open;
timeInterval1.StartEdge = IntervalEdge.Open;

var timeInterval2 = new TimeInterval(start2, end2);
timeInterval2.EndEdge = IntervalEdge.Open;
timeInterval2.StartEdge = IntervalEdge.Open;

var periods = new TimePeriodCollection
{
    t1,t2
};
var periodIntersector = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();

var intersectedPeriods = periodIntersector.IntersectPeriods(periods);

Console.WriteLine($"intersected days: {intersectedPeriods.Duration.Days}");
Console.WriteLine($"intersected days: {t1.GetIntersection(t2).Duration.Days}");
```

Output:

```
intersected days: 1
intersected days: 1
```

Comment: It's acting as if the `end1` end time is "open" (i.e. the start time is NOT included in the range). However the documentation states that the default is "closed" so that shouldn't be happening. What happens if you init end1 as: `var end1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 15) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);` ?

Comment: To clarify: `new DateTime(2023, 7, 15);`  would give you midnight at the start of the 15th and if that was an "open" interval it means it wouldn't be included in the range, and the last day of the range would therefore be the 14th.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have edited the question and added what you suggested, but I still get the wrong result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that it is calculating the overlap as a continuous time range.

When you specify an end time of `new DateTime(2023, 7, 15)`, that's specifying the midnight at the start of the 15th so it doesn't include the rest of the 15th.

When the library overlaps that with the other time range, it doesn't overlap ANY of the the 15th (except maybe one tick at the start, but I can't really see that in the results).

To include the entirety of the 15th you'd actually have to set the end time to midnight on the 16th.

It does look like there is a subtlety in the open/closed time period handling.

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using Itenso.TimePeriod;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var start1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 11);
        var end1   = new DateTime(2023, 7, 16);

        var start2 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
        var end2   = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1);

        var periods = new TimePeriodCollection
        {
            new TimeInterval(start1, end1, startEdge: IntervalEdge.Closed, endEdge: IntervalEdge.Open),
            new TimeInterval(start2, end2, startEdge: IntervalEdge.Closed, endEdge: IntervalEdge.Closed),
        };

        var periodIntersector  = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
        var intersectedPeriods = periodIntersector.IntersectPeriods(periods);
        Console.WriteLine($"intersected days: {intersectedPeriods.Duration.TotalDays}");
    }
}
```

This outputs `intersected days: 1.9999999999988427`.

You might think that it should be outputting `2.0` but because of the `endEdge: IntervalEdge.Open` for the first interval, it does NOT include the midnight at the start of the 16th in the period - which means that it also doesn't include the midnight at the end of the 15th (since they are both the same time).

Therefore it omits one tick from the calculation. In order to get it to calculate what you want you have to actually INCLUDE the end by specifying `endEdge: IntervalEdge.Closed`.

Because `IntervalEdge.Closed` is actually the default, you can omit those altogether, and get the correct result by specifying end of `end1` as the 16th in your original code:

```
using System;
using Itenso.TimePeriod;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var start1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 11);
        var end1   = new DateTime(2023, 7, 16);

        var start2 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
        var end2   = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1);

        var periods = new TimePeriodCollection
        {
            new TimeRange(start1, end1),
            new TimeRange(start2, end2),
        };
        var periodIntersector  = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
        var intersectedPeriods = periodIntersector.IntersectPeriods(periods);
        Console.WriteLine($"intersected days: {intersectedPeriods.Duration.Days}");
    }
}
```

---

Also: Be aware of the difference between `Duration.Days` (which is `int` and does not include partial days) and `Duration.TotalDays` (which is `double` and does include partial days).

Comment: Nice solution. So I added one second to all my end dates and I apply Math.Ceiling to the totalDays and it works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
DateTime start1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 11);
DateTime end1 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 15);
DateTime start2 = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
DateTime end2 = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1);            
var dates1 = new List<DateTime>();
var dates2 = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = start1; dt <= end1; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
dates1.Add(dt);
}
for (var dt = start2; dt <= end2; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
 dates2.Add(dt);
}

MessageBox.Show("intersected days="+dates1.Intersect(dates2).Count().ToString());//change here console writeline its for winform code
```